# Can multimaps be implemented with structures as key? If yes then how?

Tags: c++, multimap

For example two structures like point and square as given below if it is possible to do so how may i insert new elements into it?

```
typedef struct _point{
int x;
int y;
}Point;
typedef struct _square{
float belowLeftX;
float belowLeftY;
}Square;
multimap <Square, Point > dictionary;
```

Comment: You'll find a detaile description of the requirements for _`Key`_ types [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap).

Comment: A map is an ordered container, the ordering is based on the keys, so naturally they need to be compared to one another (using `operator<`). Also, don't prepend your type names with an underscore.

Comment: Thanks for your response, So i think it is better to look for some other solution then ? @M.A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a structure as key is not different compared to a class as key. You have two options to get your code working.

Option 1:
Supply ordering to the Square type.

```
typedef struct _square {
    float belowLeftX;
    float belowLeftY;
    bool operator<(struct _square const& rhs) const
    {
        if (belowLeftX < rhs.belowLeftX) return true;
        if (rhs.belowLeftX < belowLeftX) return false;
        return belowLeftY < rhs.belowLeftY;
    }
```

Option 2:
Supply ordering of the Square type to the dictionary.

```
auto comparator = [](Square const& lhs, Square const& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.belowLeftX < rhs.belowLeftX) return true;
    if (rhs.belowLeftX < lhs.belowLeftX) return false;
    return lhs.belowLeftY < rhs.belowLeftY;
};

std::multimap <Square, Point, decltype(comparator)> dictionary(comparator);
```